# BehaviorSubject doesn't emit values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

i have a problem with emiting values from behavior subject after switchMap operator from parent to child component. If i call real http API in console.log in child compoennt i only see empty array [] (default value), but in tap operator in parent component if i console.log data i saw array with 20 items, but in child component not. When i tried to make a mock service and return mocked data.

eg. `return of(['item1', 'item2']`

This case works fine, but when i only switched call service name, it doesn't work correctly for me, in tap i see data, but in child input not.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppserviceService } from './appservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  refresh$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
  data$: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

  constructor(private _appService: AppserviceService) {
    this.refresh$
      .pipe(switchMap(() => this._appService.test2()))
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('Subscribe:');
        console.log(res);
        this.data$.next(res)
      });

    this.refresh$.next();
  }
}
```

Child component

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() set test(value: BehaviorSubject<any[]>) {
    console.log(value.getValue());
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7wezwh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Did you met with this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: try console log data before this line ```this.childData$.next(data);```

Comment: Try replacing ```refresh$ = new Subject();``` with ```refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject();```

Comment: When i console.log data, i saw results. And I think, behavior subject is not correct, because i don't need any default value. But i tried it with default null value and doesn't work too. There is an example on stackblitz. In service i have two API, one mock, second real API. Mock works fine, but second not.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7wezwh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your child component gets instantiated before your http call completes. Right now you are only `getValue()`ing the first value. If you want the `BehaviorSubject` to emit new data every time it has one, you can fix this by simply adding the async operator:

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}" [test]="data$ | async"></hello>
```

```js
@Input() set test(value: any[]) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Now every time the `BehaviorSubject` has a new value, it will be emitted to your child component

[Fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmakcd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)